# Laravel Blade: Use commands from string

Tags: laravel, dynamic, command, laravel-blade

I have variable in Controller:

```
$abc = '@include('partials.formerror', array(.....))';
```

And I send that variable to view:

```
\View::share([
    "abc" => $abc,
]);
```

And I want in view:

```
......
......

@include('partials.formerror', array(....)

......
......
```

@include('partials.formerror', array(....) is **dynamic content from Controller**. But it's **COMMAND** of Blade, not **plain text**. How can I do that?

Comment: you should compose view to do this kind of operations

Comment: @AlirezaRahmani: can you explain for detail?

Comment: you want load view file in blade that comes from controller , is it true?

Comment: @AlirezaRahmani: Yes, use blade command

Answer (score 0):

You need a string blade compiler like this one:

https://packagist.org/packages/wpb/string-blade-compiler

Laravel doens't allow blade rendering from strings out of the box.
Fyi: you could also use Blade::compileString which imho is not an elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

your answer is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

You can create a view composer and attache dynamic content to your view.